# Importing tables from web to google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I would like to import series of tables from a page which only shows a table at a time, rest can be selected by dropdown. Is there a way I can add values of table without importing hundreds of tables and processing? For example I would like to import all tables of this page
http://www.demoscope.ru/weekly/ssp/emp_lan_97_uezd.php?reg=1 to *reg=949 . First 2 columns are the same in all tables but columns 3-5 are different. I would like to get a final table adding columns 3-5 in all tables. Is it possible? Or how to import multiple tables at once? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
={      IMPORTHTML(A1&1; "table"; 7)\ 
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1&2; "table"; 7); "select Col3,Col4,Col5")\
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1&3; "table"; 7); "select Col3,Col4,Col5")\
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1&4; "table"; 7); "select Col3,Col4,Col5")\
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1&5; "table"; 7); "select Col3,Col4,Col5")\
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1&6; "table"; 7); "select Col3,Col4,Col5")\
  QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1&7; "table"; 7); "select Col3,Col4,Col5")}
```

where A1:

```
http://www.demoscope.ru/weekly/ssp/emp_lan_97_uezd.php?reg=
```

[image]